# Jquery- How to remove comma after a specific record in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using the datatables `mRender` function to generate a list of items in a column separated by commas. I wanted to remove a specific record from the list and the record lies at the end of list of records in an array. Something like this:

```
LESS,SAAS,REST,API
```

I want to remove the last record (API, which i did), however, when i remove it the comma still sticks to it at the end, resulting into something like:

```
LESS,SAAS,REST,
LESS,SAAS,
```

assuming that all time the record after the comma is the `ALL`. How can i remove the record and also the comma that sticks after it??
EDIT: This is how i have the code and im removing the `API`, by passing empty string. Please suggest of this could be done better.

```
mRender: function (obj) {
    _.each(obj, function(item, index){
        var prodVal = "";

        else if (item === 'API'){
            prodVal = '';
        }

        returnVal.push("<span class='product'>" + prodVal + "</span>");
    });

    return returnVal.join(', ');
}
```

Any ideas???

Thanks!

Comment: How are you removing it now? `LESS,SAAS,REST,API` is a string, right?

Comment: Thanks all for such prompt response. I'll try them now!!!

Comment: No problem. You should be turning your string into an array, then removing the last value by using .pop, lastly use .join to see the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Removing the last element

Depending on whether you're working with an array, object, or string, there are a few different ways to handle it.  With your example, it looks like your setting the value to empty, rather than removing the entry, which is why you're getting an extra comma after using `returnVal.join(', ')`.

#### Remove last element from array

```
var mRecord = ["LESS","SAAS","REST","API"];
mRecord.pop();

console.log(mRecord); // Array( [0] => "LESS", [1] => "SAAS", [2] => "REST" )
console.log(mRecord.join()); // String "LESS,SAAS,REST"
```

#### Remove last element from string

```
// with simple built-in functions - will perform better in your example
mRecord = mRecord.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf(",") - 1);

// with regex - may perform better with larger strings
mRecord  = mRecord.replace(/,[^,]+$/, "");
```

#### Remove the last member of an object

While I am uncertain as to the structure of the object you are working with, you should likely be using some variation of `delete mRecord[member]`.

Currently, `prodVal = ''` leaves the entry in the array, causing `returnVal.join(', ')` to include an extra ', ' between the last value, and the empty one.

Your code includes an `else if` but not the initial `if` declaration. I suspect that if you move the push and returns within the main conditional, it may work as you intend

```
mRender: function (obj) {
    _.each(obj, function(item, index){
        var prodVal = "";

        if (item === 'API'){
            prodVal = '';
            // edit: your best bet is to generate a new array or object to act on
            //       rather than trying to unset the item here.
        } else {
            returnVal.push("<span class='product'>" + prodVal + "</span>");
        }
        
    });
    return returnVal.join(', ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but I think that splitting the string into an array, filtering out the array, and then joining back into a string will be the most robust & flexible.

Something like this:

```
var items = 'LESS,SAAS,REST,API'.split( ',' );
items = items.filter(function( item ) { /* return false for anything you want to remove */ });
console.log( items.join( ',' ) );
```

A few relevant links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 var str = "LESS,SAAS,REST,API";
 var res = str.split(",");
 res.pop();
 console.log(res.join(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = 'LESS,SAAS,REST,';
list = list.substring(0, list.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. explode into array i.e. `var arr = 'LESS,SAAS,REST,API'.split(',')`
2. remove element i.e. `av.splice(av.length-1,1); //<- removes last element`
3. Join again to generate string `av.join(',')`

Answer (score 0):

this will remove the 7 from this example array showing how the `splice` works

```
var anArray = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7" ];        
anArray.splice(-1);
```

will give 123456 (without the 7 the last element in the array)

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/4fthtkL7/) showing it in action

Answer (score -1):

This is a **very simple** function exactly for what you need. Try it out and let me know what you think:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        var string = "LESS,SAAS,REST,API";
        var array = string.split(",");

        function delete_last(elem) {
            var index = array.indexOf(elem);
            array.splice(index, 1);
            return array.join(",");
        }

        var results = delete_last("API");

        console.log(results);

    });
```

Comment: No reason for down votes. Please explain why if you down voted. Thanks

Comment: I'm a little curious too. It does answer the question, but I'm guessing because it cannot be applied to the problem as it was posed. Maybe a rewording of the question is in order...